# Remove brackets (and text within brackets) from a sentence

Tags: python

I have a text that contains a lot of brackets with text between it. For removing these brackets (and text) I wrote this:

```
import re
def generalDatacleaning(mystring):
  result = re.sub(r'[]', '', mystring)
  print(result)
```

Running this on a sample sentence however gives me "ete" (the insides of the bracket):

```
test = "[ete], this is a text"
generalDatacleaning(test)
```

What should I change so the [text] part is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
re.sub(r"\[[^]]*\]", "", test)
```

Starts with the opening bracket, takes everything within it that is not a closing bracket, takes the closing bracket. Replace it all with an empty string.

Much more efficient than .*? (doesn't require what's called "Backtracking") and works with newlines within the brackets too.